# Mouse Hovering issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I'm working on a hover effect. On hovering it is changing size but the issue is that size is changing when I hover the mouse anywhere on the row which contains the h3 text.

I'd rather it to work only when i hover the mouse on the h3 text.

A second issue is that the position is not absolute. That is, the postion of nearby stuff gets changed when hovering take place.

This is my jquery code:

```
var bindBehaviors = function (scope) {
        $('h3',scope).hover(
        function () {
        $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
        },
       function () {
       $(this).css("font-size", "25px");
       }
       );
       }
       bindBehaviors(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `<span>` in your `<h3>`:

```
<h3>
    <span>Text</span>
</h3>
```

And bind your event to the span instead:

```
var bindBehaviors = function(scope) {
    $('h3 span', scope).hover(function () {
        $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("font-size", "25px");
    });
}

bindBehaviors(this);
```

Comment: Great.it is working now.Can you tell why span is working with this.?
But still positioning issue is left.

Comment: As for the positioning issue. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ASt8z/2 . You will have to take the size increase into account, by setting the height of your h3 to the maximum height it will become after the text increase.